# Ruby On Rails - Myspace app development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, myspace

Which gem or plugin should I use for building Myspace applications using Ruby on Rails?

Answer (score 1):

MySpace provides a REST API Ruby Library:

http://developer.myspace.com/community/libs/ruby.aspx

I don't know if it's any good.

Answer (score 0):

There's also a Spacer gem. I wasn't able to get it working, however.

http://www.railslodge.com/ruby_gems/18-spacer-

Answer (score 0):

Here's a snippet of code for the OAUTH gem:

http://developer.myspace.com/Community/forums/p/3626/15947.aspx

I was unable to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

Another snippit of code for the OAUTH gem:

http://developer.myspace.com/Community/forums/p/804/12424.aspx

Also unable to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

A large part of developing on myspace must be done through the REST api that myspace provides, as well as ajax calls to import the response. Unfortunately you're not allowed to use an iFrame until OpenSocial 0.9 which wont be out for a while. Until then become familiar with MySpace's API and ajax.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the myspace-ruby-sdk http://code.google.com/p/myspaceid-ruby-sdk/

There are a sample of Rails application ( 2.2.2 version ) into